# The managed path sites/MySite is not a managed path in this tenant

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, csom

Why am I getting this error? This is my Code referred from [here](https://www.morgantechspace.com/2016/02/get-all-sites-and-subsites-in-sharepoint-online-csom.html) getting all sites and subsites, but instead of giving username and password directly I used a certificate authentication like [this](https://laurakokkarinen.com/authenticating-to-office-365-apis-with-a-certificate-step-by-step/) . The flow works just fine but throws this error "The managed path sites/MySite is not a managed path in this tenant." when the GetSubSite() function is called recursively for the 1st time. Like for the Site: https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/MySite, when there are two subsites for SiteCollection MySite, then subsites 1's Url will be passed as a parameter for the GetSubSite() function as the 1st recursion that's when this error throws. What am I doing wrong?

```
public SiteStats GetSubSite(string Url, int siteLevel)
{
    using(var context = new ClientContext(adminSiteUrl))
    {
        var tenant = new Tenant(context);
        var site = tenant.GetSiteByUrl(Url);
        context.Load(site, w => w.RootWeb);
        var web = site.RootWeb;
        context.Load(web, w => w.Webs);
        context.ExecuteQuery();
        WebCollection webCollection = web.Webs;
        var siteStats = new SiteStats(siteLevel);
        try
        {
            if (webCollection.Count > 0)
            {
                siteLevel++;
                context.Load(webCollection, someProperties);
                context.ExecuteQuery();
                foreach (var webIt in webCollection)
                {
                    var webItem = site.OpenWeb(webIt.ServerRelativeUrl);
                    context.Load(webItem);
                    context.ExecuteQuery();
                    GetSubSite(webItem.Url, siteLevel);
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `GetSiteByURL` can only be used to get a top-level site collection, if you pass it the url of a subsite, it will fail.  From what I am seeing, it would be more efficient to do this in a loop **without** recursion.  Is there a particular reason you are trying to do this recursively?

Comment: Yes I'm doing this recursively to get every site and subsite in a tenant. So doing this way is easier. See the reference I've added to see what exactly I'm trying to do.

Comment: The post you referred to gives you your answer.  The API methods that retrieve a top-level site collection `Site` are different than those used to retrieve subsites `Web`.  Thus you have to have a parent function that retrieves the information about the top-level site, and then call a function for each subsite, and if any of those subsites also have subsites, only then can it recursively call the same function.